# Linking a mobile device to a useraccount

Tags: authentication, mobile, smartphone

For an assignment I have to make the CMS-system easily accessible trough mobile devices. Ideally we would like to create a way for user authentication with the least amount of input possible.

I have created a system with php/javascript which mimics the android pattern lock, so at this moment a user can login by swiping a pattern. But the problem remains that they still have to manually type a username.

Would it be possible to get some sort of unique ID from a smartphone, so we can store this in the database and link it to an account. So that if a user wants to login in to the CMS, he only has to browse the website, the system will recognize who he is, he swipes his pattern and the user is authenticated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to get a unique device id from a browser.

However, you can do it like this:

[image: Remmeber me]

If remember me is checked, you can set a [cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) on the client's browser where you store the username. Next time the user opens the page, you check if the cookie is set. If so, you prefill the username.

This way the user would only have to enter the username the first time and it will be prefilled until he deletes the cookies of his browser or the cookie expires.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the moment I have implemented a pretty decent system, which i'm trying to get more secure now. Basicly when a user logs in with his username/password he has to swipe a code which will encrypt his credentials and store them in the local storage. When he wants to login the next time he only gets a swipewindow, swipes the code. Credentials get decrypted and transmitted to the ajax page to log in.